# why don't my jsf tags work?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In Eclipse JUNO, I started:

1. new Dynamic Web Project
2. Name: JSFTest; Configuration: JavaServer Faces v2.0 Project
3. JSF Capabilites:
   [image]
4. Copy jars to WEB-INF/lib (jstl-api, jstl-impl, jsf-api, jsf-impl):

   [image]
5. new HTML to WebContent: index.xhtml with "New Facelet Composition Page", and the code inside:

   [image]
6. in web.xml, I write the index.xhtml into the welcome part
7. when I run it on my apache tomcat 7 server, the result (don't bother about the h1 title):

   [image]

So why doesn't it show the outtext and the button? What did I wrong? I saw a lot of video on youtube, I followed them, in the video it worked, but at me.

Comment: thank you, we figurated it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have to access to the `index.xhtml` page under `/faces/` virtual folder as stated in your `web.xml` file for the `FacesServlet` url mapping.

A simple way to make your JSF page to work is to change the url mapping in your `web.xml`

From:

```html
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To

```html
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you don't want to change this, you must change your `welcome-file` to `/faces/index.xhtml`.

IMO it will be better the first option, in this way the `FacesServlet` will only process the `xhtml` pages, using the `/faces/*` will make it process any other resource as images, CSS and JS files.

Comment: doesn't work.. in web.xml I have this now:

`<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>/faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>`

and i got this from chrome:

_HTTP Status 404 - /JSFTest/faces/index.jsp_

Comment: @victorio my answer says that you should do only once of those changes, not both. To solve this, just revert the changes for the `welcome-file` to `index.xhtml`

Comment: now: `HTTP Status 404 - /JSFTest/index.jsp`

why is it looking for jsp???

Comment: I don't know that. Make sure your `index` file is called `index.xhtml` as well and is in the root of `WebContent` folder. If you still have problems, please update your question and **add** the `web.xml` file content. Do not delete the previous question content. Also, make sure you have JSF 2.x libraries (it looks like you have JSF 1.2 libraries in `WEB-INF/lib`).

Comment: WORKS! the 1.2 was the problem! thank you very much! :)