# JSF tags are not being rendered

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, jsf-2

I'm starting a JSF project (this is the first time I've used JSF) and I'm having problems with the tags being rendered. I'm developing in Eclipse and using TomCat as a server.

- My login.jsp file: https://gist.github.com/code-curve/e7e557262d407dddd1f3
- My web.xml file: https://gist.github.com/code-curve/52902b7605b780dea93f
- Eclipse project structure: http://snag.gy/P8Sts.jpg
- Server startup log: https://gist.github.com/code-curve/d1927a636052607ce16a

I am accessing the file with this url: `http://localhost:8080/DeutschAkademie/login.jsp` and 
as I understand the `<h:form>` tag should render as `<form>`, but instead it's instead rendering as `<h:form>`. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I remember, in order for JSF pages to be processed by FacesServlet, they should be accessed by the pattern defined in web.xml (login.faces in your example).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two advices:

1. Update the URL pattern for Faces Servlet. The default configuration can be for `*.jsp` (no need to use `*.faces` or something else. Still, I would recommend using `*.xhtml`.
2. JSF 2 works with Facelets, so you don't need to use old JSP anymore. By reading your login.jsp page content, you can just rename the extension from jsp to xhtml and it will work.

Based on these, the *web.xml* will look like this:

```xml
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And having `login.xhtml` file.

To access to your page you will only need to write `http://localhost:8080/DeutschAkademie/login.xhtml` in your browser address bar.

Related:

- [why don't my jsf tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15046821/1065197)

---

EDIT:

Based on the picture of your project, the *WEB-INF/lib* folder is clean. You should drop the JSF 2 libraries there. Add them, recompile your project and try it again.

Comment: Ok, I changed my web.xml file and renamed my login.jsp to login.xhtml. Now that page shows a 404 with the following messages: 

`type Status report

message Servlet Faces Servlet is not available

description The requested resource (Servlet Faces Servlet is not available) is not available.`

Comment: @DanPrince make sure your project contains the JSF 2 libraries in *WEB-INF/lib*. From the picture you posted, this folder is **empty**.

Comment: Yes, which libraries exactly should there be in there, and where do I get them?

Comment: @DanPrince you can find the JSF libraries for Mojarra [here](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html), specifically [here for JSF 2.1](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/2.1/download.html)

Comment: Fantastic. All working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

When you create your project, the `web.xml` will be generated for you and as default the `servlet-mapping` inside of this file will look like that:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

It expect that you will put all your`.xhtml` files under a folder called `faces`.
So you can create this folder called `faces` under `WebContent` and put your `.xhtml` files there and than call your application `http://localhost:8080/DeutschAkademie/faces/login.xhtml`.
 
Or you can edit your `web.xml` and change the servlet-ammping to

```
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

and than call your application `http://localhost:8080/DeutschAkademie/login.xhtml`. 
Those Solutions have also been mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

After addding `<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>`, ensure your files have extension .xhtml, otherwise will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your web.xml to

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/faces/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

rename your file to login.xhtml

open your file at `http://localhost:8080/DeutschAkademie/faces/login.xhtml`

Comment: Not necessary to change the pattern. It still should be accessible as `login.faces`.

Comment: Ok, I've done both of those, and now it's 404ing at that URL.