# Java Server Faces text box and submit button not showing up

Tags: java

I cant see the submit button or the text box all I see is First Name: and Last Name: no text box or submit button.

I copied the code from a video I seen and it worked in the video I have no idea why it doesn't work for me?

Can anyone help?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- index.xhtml -->
<!-- Registration form that demonstrates various JSF components -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
<title>Books Database</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h1>Books Database</h1>
<h:form>    
First Name:<h:inputText id="firstNameInputText"/>  
<h:inputText id ="firstName" value="#{firstName}" />
<br/><br/>
Last name:<h:inputText id ="lastName" value="#{lastName}" />
<h:commandButton value="Submit" /> 
</h:form>     
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253366/jsf-tags-are-not-being-rendered

Comment: if you can't get the elements to render from the advice in the above link then post your web.xml file as well and we may be able to better diagnose the issue

Comment: there is no webXML file, is that the problem? I thought JAVA SERVER FACES is suppose to generate that

Comment: I've never come across a jsf application that has not used a web.xml file, not saying it isn't possible to deploy to server without a web.xml, just that I've always seen/used a web.xml

Comment: as far as I know, the web.xml contains key details that a server parses to run a deployed application

Comment: ok trying to figure out how to generate a webXML file right now

Comment: all you really need is the code written in the accepted answer in the above link. except for <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> you'd want to change the value to *.jsp

Comment: html formatted, typos fixed

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I created a new project and when I did it generated the xml file and the input box and submit button now show up